# How can I extract useful data out of a molecule?

Tags: feature-engineering, feature-construction

In my dataframe, I have a feature with molecules like C1=CC=C(C=C1)C(=O)OC2=CC=CC3=C2C=CC=C3O, and C1=CC=C(C=C1)CCCNC(=O)/C(=C/C2=CC(=C(C=C2)O)O)/C#N.

I have no experience with RDKit and deepchem, and unable to utilise those features effectively. If someone has any idea, kindly let me know. If you can provide some code, it would be even better.